# Retrieve two highest values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table **records** with one column *value*, and I have 10 records in it like,

10,2,5,6,9,4,1,7,8,3.  I want to get two maximum or highest values eg. 9 and 10, what will be the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it

```
SELECT value
  FROM records
 ORDER BY value DESC
 LIMIT 2
```

Output:

```
| VALUE |
|-------|
|    10 |
|     9 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59161/1)** demo

Comment: I got the answer , thnx

Comment: @zniz You're quite welcome. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * 
from records 
order by value desc 
limit 2
```

Comment: I got the answer , thnx